# Setting strokeColor of MaterialCardView outline makes it go grey no matter what

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, stroke, materialcardview

I have a MaterialCardView for a RecyclerView, each element has its importance and the outline of each element should be the corresponding colour.

Here is my XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:strokeColor="@color/low_importance_green"
        app:strokeWidth="@dimen/cardview_border_width"
        app:rippleColor="@color/low_importance_green">
```

And here the code where the colour should be set:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val colour = when (viewModel.importance){
            1 -> R.color.high_importance_red
            2 -> R.color.medium_importance_yellow
            else -> R.color.low_importance_green
    }
    holder.card.setRippleColorResource(colour)
    holder.card.strokeColor = colour

}
```

Simply applying the strokeColor in xml (and not changing colour) works fine:

[IMAGE: Setting via xml (once)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NAKa.png)

But using the onBindViewHolder() to change the strokeColor, I get this:

[IMAGE: setting via code individually fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfhBy.png)

And just to be sure, the ripple colour that is set for the cardview works fine and has no issues.

**What could lead to this behaviour?**

*I have one guess, which might be something about the MaterialTheme being applied because the grey has some very slight purple to it. But why should it and how do i fix that?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you use the API.

If you take a look at the source code of [MaterialCardView#setStrokeColor](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.java#L215) you will see that the method requires `@ColorInt`. `@ColorInt` means that the variable represents a packed color int, `AARRGGBB`.

However, in your code you are referring to a resource address (aka `@ColorRes`). This is a color resource reference (e.g. `android.R.color.black`).

```
    val colour = when (viewModel.importance){
            1 -> R.color.high_importance_red
            2 -> R.color.medium_importance_yellow
            else -> R.color.low_importance_green
    }
```

As long as both the resource (`@ColorRes`) and the actual color value (`@ColorInt`) are both `integers` the method is working but doing a completely different thing from what you expected to see.

To convert your `reference` to `color` you need to extract it from the resources using [`Resources#getColor` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)).

Luckily, there is a `compat` version [`ContextCompat#getColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getColor(android.content.Context,int))

To fix the problem you need to change

```
holder.card.strokeColor = colour
```

with

```
holder.card.strokeColor = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.card.context, colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
val colour = when (viewModel.importance){
        1 -> R.color.high_importance_red
        2 -> R.color.medium_importance_yellow
        else -> R.color.low_importance_green
}
holder.card.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colour))
```